# Python - cant access a variable within the class

Tags: python

I have a basic python question. I'm working on a class `foo` and I use `__init__():` to do some actions on a value:

```
class foo():
  def __init__(self,bar=None):
    self.bar=bar
    if bar is None: 
       isSet=False  
    else:
       isSet=True
  print isSet
```

When I execute the code I get: `NameError: name 'isSet' is not defined`.
How can I access `isSet`? What am I doing wrong?

regards,
martin

Comment: Your class name should be `Foo` as class names should use CapitalizedWords convention according to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: And his member should be is_set, too, since members use lowercase_with_underscores.

Answer (score 4):

Wrong indentation, it should be this instead, otherwise you're exiting the function.

```
class foo():
  def __init__(self,bar=None):
    self.bar=bar

    if bar is None: 
       isSet=False  
    else:
       isSet=True

    print isSet
```

Comment: Yeah I want to execute it in the context of the class. So the indentation is correct. I want to access isSet from code located in the class, not in def __init__()

Comment: @Martin: Then it doesn't make sense, because `__init__` is run only when an instance is created, not when the class is being created. What you *really* trying to do?

Comment: I want to do the following:  a=foo(bar=0x03). Then check if if bar is set when i create the object (imho this should be done with __init__()) Then I want to work with that `bar` within the class. Meaning, I want to perform different actions depending on the values of the variable `bar`. I hope you understand. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Martin: Still can't see why you need it in the class scope. Code there is executed when the type is created, long before any instances can be made, so you can't access anything that would be a result of `__init__` (or any other method).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you are trying to do. You probably want `isSet` to be a member of `foo`:

```
class foo():
  def __init__(self,bar=None):
    self.bar=bar
    self.isSet=True
    if bar is None: 
       self.isSet=False  

f = foo()
print f.isSet
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try

```
class foo():
  def __init__(self,bar=None):
    self.bar = bar
    self.is_set = (bar is None)
```

Then inside the class

```
...
def spam(self, eggs, ham):
    if self.is_set:
        print("Camelot!")
    else:
...
```

Have you read [the doc's tutorial's entry about classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `isSet` is a *class* attribute, as opposed to an *instance* attribute. Therefore in the class body you need to define it before referencing it in the `print` statement. Outside the class and in its methods, you must prefix it with the class name and a dot, i.e. `Foo.` in this case. Note that the code in `def __init__()` function body does not execute until you create an instance of the `Foo` class by calling it.

```
class Foo(object):
    isSet = None

    def __init__(self, bar=None):
        self.bar = bar

        if bar is None:
           Foo.isSet = False
        else:
           Foo.isSet = True

    print isSet

f = Foo()
print Foo.isSet
```

output:

```
None
False
```

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of the final line makes it execute in the context of the class and not `__init__`. Indent it one more time to make your program work.

Comment: It's exactly what I want, I want to execute it in the context of the class, and not in `init`

Comment: @Martin What does "execute in the context of the class" means? If it means inside a member method, see answers, if it means at class declaration you can't access anyhing created in `__init__` there, because `__init__ `has never been called.